# Symfony spool email not working with php 5.5

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, spool

I am suing my symfony2 project and sending spool messages with this command:

```
php /var/www/myproject/app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```

This works for PHP 5.3 but not for PHP5.5

In the 5.5, only the email to my local domain are send and not outside ones, For 5.3, everything works fine.

Did you encountered this problem? Any idea why`?

Comment: did you check log-files?

Comment: Sure, but there is nothing interesting. I am using the php-cli to send those spool emails. I am also using exim4 as the smtp server. In there, I can't fine anything interesting.

Comment: Can you send mail synchroneously?

Comment: Are you generating the emails with php v5.3, and then trying to send them with PVP v5.5?

Comment: @AlisterBulman, no, I am generating the emails with 5.5 and when trying to send with 5.5, it doesn't work, so I have to send them with 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished by compiling the PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. This resolved the problem but it is not a proper answer for this question. So why PHP 5.5 CLI is not working properly with this command:

```
php /var/www/myproject/app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```